Activity deslizable verticalmente android studio
Estoy diseñando una app en android studio de un reproductor de audios, es similar a las plataformas de musica con un listado para seleccionar una canción y los botones típicos de un reproductor.
Mi consulta es:
¿Como se puede diseñar la funcionalidad de la típica pantalla deslizable verticalmente encima de la activity principal para mostrar el detalle del audio que se esta reproduciendo en ese momento ?
Adjunto una captura de "referencia iOS" de lo que necesito diseñar para android studio


Por favor alguna orientación, ejemplo o algún link de cómo lograr este diseño de una activity deslizable encima de otra pensando en este tipo de aplicaciones.
Muchas gracias.
